# How to change date format in Linux Redhat

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, rhel

Is it possible to change date format from example `Fri 12 Feb 18:27:34 +08 2021` to just simply `DD-MM-YYYY`?

Specifically, to change date format in `last` command

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Where do you want to change the date format? In the output of the `date` command? In some other command or application? (Which one?)

Comment: @klez `date format` isn't a specific thing that applies to a Linux box. The current date/time is stored in some internal format on the box and then every command you run that can display a date/time displays that internal format in whatever external format it wants. So if you want to know how to change the way a specific command displays the date then you have to look at the man page for that command and don't assume the results will be the same for every other command.

Comment: If after checking the man page  you find that `last` (whatever that is) doesn't have options to let you specify the date/time format it outputs then [edit] your question to show an example of what it does output so we can help you convert that to the format you want.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this directly. Reading the documentation (`man last`) suggests the `--time-format` option, but that only offers a few choices and no user-definable formatting. Here's the default output format:

```
last
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        Sat Feb 13 16:21   still logged in
roaima   pts/1        :pts/0:S.0       Mon Feb  8 13:42 - 22:47  (09:05)
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        Mon Feb  8 13:42 - 22:47  (09:05)
roaima   pts/2        10.1.1.16        Fri Jan 15 13:57 - 02:04  (12:06)
reboot   system boot  4.19.0-13-amd64  Tue Jan 12 01:19   still running

wtmp begins Fri Jan  8 10:10:13 2021
```

Fortunately one of the options (`iso`) presents the date in a relatively easily editable format:

```
last --time-format iso
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        2021-02-13T16:21:47+00:00   still logged in
roaima   pts/1        :pts/0:S.0       2021-02-08T13:42:08+00:00 - 2021-02-08T22:47:14+00:00  (09:05)
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        2021-02-08T13:42:07+00:00 - 2021-02-08T22:47:14+00:00  (09:05)
roaima   pts/3        10.1.1.16        2021-01-15T13:57:27+00:00 - 2021-01-16T02:04:26+00:00  (12:06)
reboot   system boot  4.19.0-13-amd64  2021-01-12T01:19:18+00:00   still running

wtmp begins 2021-01-08T10:10:13+00:00
```

Stripping the time component from the ISO formatted datestamp gives this

```
last --time-format iso | sed -E 's/T[[:digit:]:+]{14}//g'
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        2021-02-13   still logged in
roaima   pts/1        :pts/0:S.0       2021-02-08 - 2021-02-08  (09:05)
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        2021-02-08 - 2021-02-08  (09:05)
roaima   pts/3        10.1.1.16        2021-01-15 - 2021-01-16  (12:06)
reboot   system boot  4.19.0-13-amd64  2021-01-12   still running

wtmp begins 2021-01-08
```

If you really want the date format in `dd-mm-yyyy` it gets more complicated because we have to parse out the day, month, year and recombine them in your order

```
last --time-format iso | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})T[[:digit:]:+]{14}/\3-\2-\1/g'
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        13-02-2021   still logged in
roaima   pts/1        :pts/0:S.0       08-02-2021 - 08-02-2021  (09:05)
roaima   pts/0        10.1.1.16        08-02-2021 - 08-02-2021  (09:05)
roaima   pts/3        10.1.1.16        15-01-2021 - 16-01-2021  (12:06)
reboot   system boot  4.19.0-13-amd64  12-01-2021   still running

wtmp begins 08-01-2021
```

(If your `sed` does not have the `-E` flag, or its equivalent `-r`, remove it and prefix every instance of these four characters `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` with a backslash. The RE just becomes much harder to read.)

Comment: "If your sed does not have the -r flag" -- the -E flag appears to be more portable. It has the same sense as `grep -E`

Comment: `-E` enables extended regular expressions on both GNU sed and Mac's BSD sed.

Comment: The MacOS `last` does not have a `--time-format` option, so the quest for portability hits a roadblock there.

Comment: If you have a `sed` with `s///e` modifier (alternatively, `perl`), then another way could be to use `date` within the substitution to parse and print the date.

Comment: @TobySpeight if you have  a sed with the `s///e` modifier then you have GNU sed and if you have GNU sed then you have GNU awk which has builtin time functions and using those will be orders of magnitude faster than using `s///e` as the latter spawns a subshell for every command it runs on every line of input. I assume the same would be true for a similar use of perl but I'd expect perl to have it's own time functions just like gawk does.

Comment: @EdMorton `perl` does have its own time functions. I briefly considered providing an alternative answer using them to try and offer a cross platform solution. An alternative answer from someone else that addressed the issue that way would definitely get a +1 from me

Comment: I would but I'm not familiar with `last` so I'm waiting for the OP to provide sample input and expected output before working on it. From reading the `last` man page it seems like parsing it's output would be about reliable as parsing  the output of `ls` though but idk for sure - maybe there's some other way of getting the information, just like there's alternatives to getting the info that `ls` displays.

Comment: @EdMorton original output included in my answer for you to try

Comment: Thanks but the format of the dates in that output (e.g. `Sat Feb 13 16:21` and `Fri Jan  8 10:10:13 2021`) don't match the one date the OP provided `Fri 12 Feb 18:27:34 +08 2021` so for whatever reason that doesn't seem to be the format that the OP is really asking for help with.

Comment: Good catch. I've checked one of my systems to look for dates from last year, and the component year is simply ignored in the default output. There is no indication of a year rollover: going backwards by one record across the year end, the datetime for one is `Tue Jan  5 10:45 - 18:11  (07:25)` and the previous is `Thu Dec 17 14:59 - 16:24  (01:25)`. On that basis it would seem that the OP has yet another version of `last`